# Using column count with ul

Tags: html, css

I wanted to split a unordered list in to two columns so i searched for a solution and found this:
 csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/

This worked fine but on certian pages you couldn't see the bullet points so i switched to using column count to balance s simple list

```
<ul class="double_column">
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
    <li>test 4</li>
    <li>test 5</li>
    <li>test 6</li>
    <li>test 7</li>
    <li>test 8</li>
    <li>test 9</li>
</ul>
```

like here http://jsfiddle.net/jZA4y/

The problem i am having is the on some lists the column count dosen't balance the list equally?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRfAF.png

What is the best way to fix this problem so that both column are equal or close as possible?

Comment: Or, you give a width to the `<li>` and let them all `float: left;` and thus creating 2 columns.

Comment: @Déjàvu - If you look at the OP's fiddle - you'll see that this is not what he wants. test2 should appear in the same column as test1

Comment: @Danield Ah ok, my bad. Didn't notice that one. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @GajMohan - the code you posted seems to balance the 2 columns correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jZA4y/16/

Comment: @Danield The fiddle is balanced fine but when i use it on  a webpage some of the columns end up like so : http://i.stack.imgur.com/oRfAF.png where there is three in one and one in another. I have even had 4 in the left column and one in the right. I am not sure what is going on

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".double_column ").find("li").count();
```

would do your work

Answer (score 0):

I think that the example of work and that it can help you `float:left;`